# how to supply a file name as an argument to shell script

Tags: shell

I want to run a shell script, run.sh

line_no=$(awk '{x++} END {print x}' #file_name#)

echo $line_no

I want to run the script on different files each time. How can supply the file_name as an argument while running this script?

Comment: The arguments passed to the script are available in the positional parameters.  `$1`, `$2`, etc.  Also available through `$*` and `$@`.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to a shell script are `$0` (the name of the script), `$1` (the first argument passed to the script), `$2` (the second argument to the script), etc.

So just use $1 in place of your filename!